# getting the sunrise time for Chatham Islands in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I'm trying to build a function that will return the sunrise and sunset times for the Chatham Islands (UTC+12:45 normally and +13:45 in summer)

I have the following code that works ok for New Zealand but returns the times for the following day when the inputs are set to Chatham.

```
<?php
$timeInUTC = "2013-08-15T00:00:01Z";
$this_tz = new \DateTimeZone("Pacific/Chatham");  
$lat = -44;
$long = -176.5;   

$startTimestamp = strtotime($timeInUTC);            
$startTime = new \DateTime($timeInUTC,$this_tz);
$offset = ($this_tz->getOffset($startTime))/3600;                   

$sunriseTimestamp = date_sunrise($startTimestamp, SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $lat, $long, 90, $offset);
$sunsetTimestamp = date_sunset($startTimestamp, SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $lat, $long, 90, $offset);


$startTimeString = date("c",$startTimestamp);
$sunriseTimeString = date("c",$sunriseTimestamp);
$sunsetTimeString = date("c",$sunsetTimestamp);

echo "At ($lat,$long) on the day of $startTimeString the sun rises at $sunriseTimeString and sets at $sunsetTimeString (offset of $offset)\n";


?>
```

This returns

`At (-44,-176.5) on the day of 2013-08-15T12:00:01+12:00 the sun rises at 2013-08-16T06:43:28+12:00 and sets at 2013-08-16T16:57:13+12:00 (offset of 12.75)`

As you can see from the print out it thinks sunrise is 18.75 hours after the specified time and sunset is 27 hours after the input time, which just isn't possible unless it was in the arctic circle and the sun was down for more than 24 hours.

So, am I using date_sunrise incorrectly, or has PHP got a bug I have to work around?

*additional*
I've tried adjusting the longitude and found that -178.9140 gives the right day for the sunrise (I have to assume the time is correct) but -178.9130 jumps forward 24 hours. All other inputs are the same

*Update*
With the change to summer time this has spread halfway across New Zealand.

Checking for the sunrise time on Oct 1st 2013 10:35 (NZ summer time) at longitude 177.25 gets 2013-10-01T06:45:18+13:00 but shift the longitude to 177.5 at the sunrise is reported as 2013-10-02T06:44:18+13:00

I've added this to the bug report at php.net (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53148) and found a work around as detailed below

Comment: I just can't believe that [date_sunrise](http://php.net/date_sunrise) is a native PHP function...

Comment: What's with the \DateTimeZone and \DateTime - aren't they throwing errors?

Comment: The \DateTimeZone and \DateTime are because I wrote this within a namespaced environment and that is to step out of that. It still runs fine in OS X's PHP (5.3.15) so I just left them there.

Comment: The Chathams' timezone is east of UTC, but the longitude you're giving is west of UTC. You could try longitude of 183.5 East.

Comment: You're giving the input time the timezone 'Z' aka 'Zulu' aka GMT+0, and then you're interpreting it in GMT+12. Can you see how your results would be wonky? Using two different timezones that happen to be on opposite sides of the planet?

Comment: Which bit do you think is interpreting it in +12? For the printout line all the values are +12 (because I am in NZ) so it is the relative time between them that matters.
The offset is either 12.75 or 12 depending on whether is am checking a NZ on Chatham time. I've also set 0 to check your theory of having the same timezone everywhere, same results, still 27 hours from the input time to the sunset time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in PHP and I've had to find a workaround.

```
$startDayOfYear = date("z",$startTimestamp);
$sunriseDayOfYear = date("z",$sunriseTimestamp);

if($startDayOfYear != $sunriseDayOfYear)
{
    $sunriseTimeString = date("c",$sunriseTimestamp." - 1 day");
    $sunsetTimeString = date("c",$sunsetTimestamp." - 1 day");
} else {
    $sunriseTimeString = date("c",$sunriseTimestamp);
    $sunsetTimeString = date("c",$sunsetTimestamp);
}
```